# How to implement Conditional Editing Logic for Editing Empty Cells in AG Grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid

I'm currently working with AG Grid where I am dynamically fetching grid data from an API and I'm facing an issue with editing cells. By default, when I set editable: true in the column definition, all cells become editable. However, I want to restrict editing to only the empty cells within the grid. Unfortunately, my attempts to implement this logic have not yielded the desired results, and I'm seeking assistance from the community to help me resolve this issue.

Here's a snippet of the column definition where I tried to implement the conditional editing logic:

```
 const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => ({
  flex: 1,
  minWidth: 180,
  filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
  filterParams: {
    filterOptions: ['startsWith', 'contains', 'equals'],
    maxNumConditions: 1,
  },
  resizable: true,
  sortable: true,
  editable: params =>
    params.value === null || params.value === undefined || params.value === '',
  cellClassRules: {
    'empty-cell': params =>
      params.value === null || params.value === undefined || params.value === '',
  },
  valueParser: params => params.newValue.trim(),
}), []);
```

```
<AgGridReact
    ref={gridRef}
    className='ag-theme-alpine'
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    defaultColDefs={defaultColDefs}
    onGridReady={onGridReady}
    onCellEditingStarted={onCellEditingStarted}
    onCellValueChanged={onCellValueChanged}
/>
```

Here, cellClassRules is working fine with the condition, highlighting only empty cells, but editing is enabled for all cells instead of empty cell.